# Regex do not start with string or do not end with string

Tags: regex, .htaccess

i'm lost in a regular expression issue.

I need to make a pattern in a htaccess file to match path that doesn't start with

`view` 
or 
doesn't end with 
`(.oet|.ttf,..)`

I can make the part for view, but not the end part.

to test view I have :

```
^(?!view)(.*)$
```

I tried to test to not end with .eot like this but it doesn't work :

```
^(.*)(?!.oet)$
```

the final test i would like should look like this :

```
^((?!view)(.\*))|((.\*)(?!.eot|.ttf|.otf|.woff))$
```

can someone help me please ?

Comment: what is the input and expected output

Answer (score 3):

`mod_rewrite` gives you flexibility of breaking it into 2 separate matches using `RewriteCond which will be much more maintainable than one single complex regex.

You can use it like this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(eot|ttf|otf|woff)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^((?!view).*)$ /view/$1 [L,NC]
```

Answer (score 0):

you need a negative lookbehind.

```
^(?!view).*?(?<!.eot|.ttf|.otf|.woff)$
```

demo here : http://regex101.com/r/dP3gS3/2